# add the record count if first part of file name is same which is in next line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have text file with file name and it’s record count; I want to add the record count if first part of files name were same:

count.txt:

```
aa_20201123.csv 1000 
bb_20201123.csv 1500
bb_20201124.csv 2500
```

Output should be:

```
aa*.csv 1000 
bb*.csv 4000
```

Comment: @Indhu   This is company type question , can you explain in detail with Output

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F'[_ ]' '
    { sum_records[$1"*.csv"] +=$NF; };
END { for (x in sum_records) print x, sum_records[x]; }' infile
```

We defined field separator to both Underscore and Space; then for every same first field we sum the records count then at the `END { ... }` block we print them.

Output:

```
bb*.csv 4000
aa*.csv 1000
```

---

files name suffix at above we hardcoded, but if you have more than just .csv, you can change as following:

```
awk -F'[_ .]' '
    { sum_records[$1 "*." $3]+=$NF; };
END { for (x in seen) print x, seen[x]; }' infile
```

note that we added dot `.` to the list of field separators too and used `$3` in place of hard-coded `"csv"`.

for an input like below:

```
aa_20201123.csv 1000
bb_20201123.csv 1500
bb_20201123.txt 1234
bb_20201124.csv 2500
```

that will gives you output as following:

```
bb*.csv 4000
aa*.csv 1000
bb*.txt 1234
```